# Magento2.3: Product quantity is not reflecting to the minicart

Tags: product, magento2.3, mini-cart, quantity

I have installed a module which is for adding increment and decrement buttons for quantity. After installing the module I can see the buttons in product detail page but when i update the quantity, it's not reflecting to the cart.

Below is the module I have used:

https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-qty

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the original implementation working in luma theme

https://github.com/DominicWatts/PlusMinusQuantity

Had to adapt the js slightly. My guess is that something has changed since the original tutorial was put together

I submitted a pull request but not merged in

https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-qty/pull/3

Perhaps that's your issue?

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! It's work great.

Comment: when I have installed and at first time i tried updating the quantity using buttons, its reflected to the cart but again it's not reflecting when I add second time